# How do you quickly descend a vertical surface while cleaning it?

Tags: dustforce

I watched a few high-level runs of some levels, and the players were able to seemingly cling to a wall, then run/fall down the wall very quickly while still cleaning the entire surface. I've found that if I just land on the wall, then falling takes quite a bit of time. If I dash downards, then I pass right by the surface without cleaning it. So I can *either* descend quickly *or* clean the surface.

How do I do both?

For example, shortly after 47 seconds in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFWzSEgb4AY#t=47s), the guy is able to slide quickly down the wall somehow. I'm not sure how he's managing to do this.

Comment: It's been a while since I've last played, but usually I would just use rapid short downward swipes while passing by the surface, or the larger swipe if the surface is small to clear with one hit. Are you sure that's not what's happening here? An example video would help.

Comment: @Mana Added a video. Maybe not the perfect example, but something that I don't know how to do. I did notice your idea of just smacking the wall as you fall past it in some other runs, which I'll have to also try out.

Answer (score 2):

The trick in that video is pretty subtle. When they approach the wall, they do a downward dash in midair(ctrl+down) to give themselves a boost in downwards momentum. Then they hit the wall at the right spot to minimize the amount of sliding they need to do to clear the wall. This way, they increase the amount of downward momentum they have entering the slide, and decrease their download momentum only a small amount while holding on to the wall. As soon as the wall is clear, they hit back to let go of the wall, and repeat the trick with the other side.